# php firebase notification sample

Tags: php, android, api, firebase

I've implemented a custom **web application**. an **android** application is gonna connected to the web application. I know I can use the **google firebase** to make it but I don't have any **sample code**. 
any suggestion or comment or source code will be **appreciated**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple PHP FireBase (**FCM**) script showing how to send an Android push notification. Be sure to replace the **SERVER_API_ACCESS_KEY** with a proper one from the Google ***API's Console*** page. To use the script, just call

[**http://sample.com/PhpFireBaseNotificationSample.php?id=THE_DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID**](http://sample.com/PhpFireBaseNotificationSample.php?id=THE_DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID)

> source code :

```
 #API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-SERVER-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
    $registrationIds = $_GET['id'];
#prep the bundle
     $msg = array
          (
        'body'  => 'Body  Of Notification',
        'title' => 'Title Of Notification',
                'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
          );
    $fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $registrationIds,
                'notification'  => $msg
            );


    $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
#Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
#Echo Result Of FireBase Server
echo $result;
```

**GitHub link of php sample code :** https://gist.github.com/MohammadaliMirhamed/7384b741a5c979eb13633dc6ea1269ce

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: yes, that was my own question. then i found my wat share it on GitHub and StackOverflow

Comment: I hope this is using the newer version (api); not tested but the referenced answers for closing the question are being superseded by the deprecation of the FCM Legacy version.